# How to notify parent's component class (using hooks) after the child is in ready state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm rendering in `index.js` the following main component:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Main/>
  )
}
```

Where `Main` component is defined as:

```
import React from "react";
export default class Main extends Child {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.ready) {
      console.log('Parent ready'); // This is NOT called!
    } else {
      console.log('Parent mounted'); // This is called fine.
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.ready != this.state.ready) {
      console.log('Parent updated'); // This is NOT called!
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And `Child` component is:

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {ready: false};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.ready) {
      // I'm loading some dynamic libraries here...
      // ...then set the state as ready.
      this.setState({ready: true});
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.ready != this.state.ready) {
      console.log('Child ready'); // This is called.
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.ready) {
      return (
        <div>Loaded.</div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

After run, console log produces the following lines:

```
Parent mounted
Child ready
```

My problem is that the parent is that never notified of child's ready state (`componentDidMount()`), neither parent's `componentDidUpdate` is called.

**How do I notify parent's class that the child is in ready state** to perform certain actions (in parent component)?

I've already tried:

- Referencing `Main` with `ref="child"` (in `index.js`) to reference parent from child instance, but had an error (*Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead*).
- Calling `super()` from Child class in different ways (such as calling hook manually).
- Used `const mainRef = useRef();` or `this.mainRef = useRef();` in different ways, but without success (more errors: *Error: Invalid hook call*).

Is there any easier way?

Comment: What is wrong with considering the child, and parent, "ready" when they've both been mounted and rendered? OFC the parent isn't "notified" of anything the child component is doing, it doesn't pass any props as a callback for the child to call to pass anything back out to the parent. Why do you have what appears to be a heavy coupling between these two component? What is the real issue you are trying to solve for? See the official docs for [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), it may help enlighten you to how children can "inform" parent components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've not understood React basics. In the simplest of terms, in React, data flows down from parent to children components in the form of props, and only back up via a callback (*generally passed as a prop*) a child component calls. Additionally, React hooks are only compatible with React function components. If you want to use a React ref in a class-based component use the `createRef` function (*see [creating refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)*).

Given:

```
export default class Main extends Child {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.ready) {
      console.log('Parent ready'); // This is NOT called!
    } else {
      console.log('Parent mounted'); // This is called fine.
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.ready != this.state.ready) {
      console.log('Parent updated'); // This is NOT called!
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The parent component's `this.state.ready` is undefined, i.e. falsey, and never updates. This is the reason only the `"Parent mounted"` log from mounting is outputted. The `prevState.ready` value always equals the `this.state.ready` value, so the `"Parent updated"` log will never be called.

React also prefers [Composition over Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html), the `Main` component should extend `React.Component`, not the `Child` component.

React components don't share state, not even when one class component extends another. The reason your code doesn't work is because your React class component is ***just*** syntactic sugar for `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`. In other words, your React class component get transpiled down to a vanilla Javascript function call that is instanceless.

See [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

In order for the child component to update a state/status in the parent component, it necessarily needs to be passed a callback function it can invoke. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for more details.

Here's a simple example refactor of your code applying this pattern.

Parent

```
import React from "react";

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    childReady: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Parent mounted');
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('Parent updated');

    if (prevState.childReady !== this.state.childReady) {
      if (this.state.childReady) {
        console.log('Parent notified Child is ready');
      }
    }
  }

  setChildReady = () => this.setState({ childReady: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child setReady={this.setChildReady} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ready: false,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.ready) {
      // I'm loading some dynamic libraries here...
      // ...then set the state as ready.
      this.setState({ ready: true });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.ready !== this.state.ready) {
      if (this.state.ready) {
        console.log('Child ready');
        this.props.setReady();
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.ready
      ? <div>Loaded.</div>
      : <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-notify-parents-component-class-using-hooks-after-the-child-is-in-ready]

Example logs:

```
Parent mounted 
Child ready 
Parent updated 
Parent notified Child is ready
```

As I've said, this is a very trivial example but it ***is*** the general basis for passing data/values/etc back up from children to parent components. You will need to tailor this pattern to suite your app's needs. For example, for more complicated state or more deeply nested children you will want to use a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to expose the common state and setters. If this isn't enough there are other global state management libraries like Redux ([Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)) that makes working with global state easier with dispatchable actions.

Answer (score 4):

State lives on the component and is not magically shared. Thus, you need to pass the state from one component to the other.

I suggest to read the react docs, they are quite useful - https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html.

But first things first - best practice for react components nowadays is to use  [Functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). To understand them, best also read the docs for the useEffect hook.

Lets rewrite your components thus and start with the main.

## Main

The state must live in the Main component and be passed down into the child, because they both need the state, but the Main is rendered first.

We can define state using the `useState` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).
As we will need both the state itself in the child as well as a function to update the state, we pass both.

```
function Main() {
  const [isChildReady, setIsChildReady] = useState(false);

  const updateParent = () => {
    setIsChildReady(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isChildReady) {
      console.log("Parent ready"); // This is NOT called!
    } else {
      console.log("Parent mounted"); // This is called fine.
    }
  }, [isChildReady]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Child isChildReady={isChildReady} setIsChildReady={updateParent} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Child

The child does not need any further useState for itself, because it already gets passed everything it needs as properties.

The useEffect hook replaces the componentDidMount method and is triggered on mounting. We use it to update the state in the parent.

```
function Child({
  isChildReady,
  setIsChildReady,
}: {
  isChildReady: boolean,
  setIsChildReady: () => void,
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsChildReady();
  });

  if (isChildReady) {
    return <div>Loaded.</div>;
  } else {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Don't fight React, lift state up

Regardless of whether you rewrite it to hooks (which you should), the answer is the same: [**lift state up**](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). It's not a direct solution to your problem, rather a way to not have the problem in the first place (which I guess is also a solution? :) ).

React advises to lift state up to the component that needs it. Since the internal state of your `Child` component needs to be known by its parent (whether it's ready or not), **this principle applies here**.

There's no real reason why you'd have to initialize these dynamic libraries from within the child component. You could just as well do this in the parent component, and then create a simpler child component that takes the resulting data as props, if any.

In your case it means removing the `Child`'s `componentDidMount` method, and executing its contents in the `Main` component's `componentDidMount` instead.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.state.ready) {
    // I'm loading some dynamic libraries here...
    // ...then set the state as ready.
    this.setState({ready: true});
  }
}
```

If state is needed by a parent component, you can just move the state to the topmost component that needs it. With hooks this is particularly easy, but even with classes it's often just moving a few lines around and adding some props.

There's no point fighting React's data flow direction if it's so easy to move up your state instead. From there it can reach any inner component using props, or context if your tree is complex.

As a result the parent already knows everything it has to, and there is no more need to notify the parent when any of its children completes.

```
function Main() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(null);
  // isReady could also be stored as state and updated in the effect.
  const isReady = appState !== null;
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    doSomeSlowTask().then(result => setAppState( doSomethingWith(result) );
  }, []);

  return <div>
    { !isReady ? <LoadingState/> : <Child state={appState}/> }
  </div>;
}

function Child({appState}) {
  return <span>Hello {appState.username}</span>;
}

function LoadingState() {
  return <span>Loading...</span>;
}
```

### Which component to extend?

Well, none, use function components... But if you do use classes, you should only extend React's base class. I see you extended your `Main` component from your `Child` component.

```
export default class Main extends Child {
```

This in practice won't do anything more than letting it extend `React.Component`, because `Child` does. Besides sharing lifecycle method implementations. But React won't put any special link between instances of the 2 classes.

I guess you assumed this would allow the components to share state, but it doesn't.